# Prove Properties of isomorphics Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have to prove something but I'm not sure I'm explainig it well, can you help me please?

Problem:

$G$ and $H$ are isomorphics and exists an biyective function $f$ of isomorphism between them.

a. Let $C$ = { $x_0$, $x_1$,...$x_k$} be a walk  of length $k$ in $G$ prove that 
$C'$ = { $f(x_0)$, $f(x_1)$,...,$f(x_k)$ is a walk of length $k$ in $H$.

Answer: Since $G$ is isomorphic to $H $ then $|V(F)| = |V(H)|$ and $|E(F)| = |E(H)|$.
We know $f$ is biyective so  for each $v_i$ in $V(G)$ exists $f(v_i)=X_j$, $x_j$ in $V(H)$  besides the isomorphism function preserves the edges if exists  $(v_i,v_j)$ in $E(G)$ then exists   $(f(v_i),f(v_j))$ in $E(H)$ then if $C$ = { $x_0$, $x_1$,...$x_k$} is a walk of length $k$ in $G$, $C'$ is of length $k$ too.

b. $G$ is connected ( I Don't know how to say it, what i'm trying to say is that exists a path between any pair of vertex)  if $G$ is connected.

Answer: As mentioned before as they are isomorphic  they preserve their edges, if $H$ is coneccted and $G$ is not it means that exists $(f(v_i),f(v_j))$ in $E(H)$ and it does'nt exist  $(v_i,v_j)$ in $E(G)$  then $|E(F)| is diferent of |E(H)|$ that can't happen because is a propertie of the isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler than you think it is. Go back to the definition of a "walk" in a graph. Each pair of adjacent vertices in the walk have to be connected by an edge in the graph (if this is true for $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, it must remain true when you apply $f$) and if $i$ and $j$ are different then the edges between $x_i,x_{i+1}$ and between $x_j,x_{j+1}$ must be distinct.

Check these conditions separately;   If $\{x_{i},x_{i+1}\}$ is an edge, is $\{f(x_{i}),f(x_{i+1})\}$ an edge? Yes; this is true by definition of a graph homomorphism. We don't even need the fact that it is an isomorphism here. For the second condition, you will need the fact that it is an isomorphism. Prove that condition is satisfied and you're done.